# xinput des not recognize properties on Fedora 25

Tags: xorg, xinput

On Fedora 25, `xinput` seems to have problems recognizing properties for input devices.

According to [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint), this should work:

```
$ xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Device Accel Profile" 2
property 'Device Accel Profile' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

Looking at the output in Setup section below, it seems, that the properties were renamed. Unfortunately, using the new property names yields the same result:

```
$ xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Accel Speed" 0.75
property 'Accel Speed' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

I also tried using the device `id` with `--type` and `--format` specified - same result.

### Setup

Fedora 25, Xorg (not Wayland), i3wm, Thinkpad TrackPoint (`TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint`)

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
...

$ xinput list-props 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint'
Device 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (276): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (277): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (278):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (279):   1, 0
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The property is called `libinput Accel Speed` (note the *libinput* at the begging). Similarly with other properties.
2. The input devices are now handled by `libinput` library (at least in Fedora 25), which supports both Wayland and X.Org. Unfortunately, it does note provide as much options as the old way (yet! - it seems to be in [rapid development](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/)).

### Notes

- `man libinput` documents all the properties
- [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput) makes a great topic summary as always
- There seems to be a [workaround](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/unable-to-change-sensitivity-acceleration-logitech-g502/14279/3) to fall back to the old method, but I did not try it.

*Since I am replying to my own question, I might have missed something important - all input appreciated.*

**EDIT** Completely forgot to mention that the TrackPoint scrolling works out of the box now, which is kind of nice :)

Comment: Whoa, works out of the box? Not on my ThinkPad E470 running Fedora 25. You didn't end up needing to change any settings to get it working now?

Comment: @dmh Yes, but I do have quite old ThinkPad.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, at least fc26 is out in a couple of months. Hopefully it works for me by then...

Comment: Trackpoint scrolling (using middle key) doesn't quite work for me as it used to before (it works in reverse order). It happened after i upgraded from fc25 to fc26. Still cannot figure out.